# How to use iOS share extension to open 1password to fill password from expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I use expo to develop a react native app, and want to use 1password to fill the account and password. When I use the react native `Share` to publish an URL, 1password doesn’t show in the iOS share extension.

Twitter iOS app shows a great share extension containing 1password and lastpass. Is it possible to do that using expo? Thanks.

[image: twitter iOS app share extension]